# Magento 1.9.1 After changing the order address from admin notification, mail is not going to customer

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, email, third-party-module, adminnotification

In Magento 1.9.1, I have placed an order for a wholesale customer from the admin. The customer receives an email of new order placement. After placing the order I notice the shipping address which I have selected is wrong.

I edit the shipping address and check on all the **3 checkboxes (Recalculate, Notification[customize],confirm update)** below the update button. I have written a note on Notification [customize] section also. After clicking on update the message display “**Order update, not yet applied. Customer has been sent an email with a confirmation link. Updates will be applied after confirmation.**”

But the customer didn’t get any mail related to address change. We have used mandrill for sending a mail. I have checked is mandrill outbound but seems that the mail is not triggered from the Magento. Other than this all the other mail is going to customer. Can anyone please tell me what is the problem? Why the address change/notification mail is not triggered from Magento ?

Comment: Did you check Cron Jobs? are those working?

Comment: I have checked cron job and they are working. Only problem with the address change confirmation mail.

Comment: I don't think "confirm update" is a Magento standard functionality. Are you using IWD Ordermanager? If so, please contact them for support. 3rd party extensions are "off topic" here.

Comment: @simonthesorcerer yes I am using the IWD ordermanager extension.

Comment: OK, as I said, you should check back with IWD then

Comment: @sv3n Yes this problem has solve. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been fix by `IWD support` and its working, they have just change 1 file.

> Changed file
>
> app/code/community/IWD/OrderManager/Model/Notify/Notification.php

They have commented the below code in `getEmails()` function.

> check below updated getEmails() function with commented code

```
protected function getEmails()
    {
//        $store_id = $this->order->getStore()->getId();
//        $data = $this->email . "," . Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_COPY_TO, $store_id);
//        if (!empty($data) && strlen($data)>5) {
//            return explode(',', $data);
//        }  // Code commented by Iwd support

        $email = $this->order->getCustomerEmail();
        return array($email);
    }
```